# How can I release a locked Hyper-V VHD that is used by another process?

Tags: hyper-v

While I was starting my vm I got this error

> Microsoft Emulated IDE Controller Error(Instance ID
>   83F863B-8DCA-9EDA-2CA8B33039B4): Failed to Power on with Error 'The
>   process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>   process .'.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Do you have the VHD attached to another running VM?

Answer (score 9):

It's also possible for Windows to lock a VHD file. I ran into this by double-clicking on a VHD, which causes recent version of Windows to open it up like a folder. However, it appears that the system then holds a lock on the file, which prevents Hyper-V from using it to start a VM. Rebooting fixed that problem.

Comment: Rebooting is overly drastic. Just open Disk Management and un-mount the VHD.

Comment: That's even better

Comment: @longneck Could you please post this as an answer so it can be marked as the solution?

Answer (score 3):

While some of the simple answers provided above may work for some users, none of them solved my issue.  My problem was that the Hyper-V .vhdx file for my virtual machine was locked but not appearing in either File Explorer as an ejectable disk nor in Administrative Tools Disk Management component.  Note that my VM is a Debian Linux derivative running under WSL2 in Windows 10 with Hyper-V enabled.

So how did it become locked in the first place?  I followed the instructions from an article on the web that said I can easily view files by simply double-clicking the .vhdx file.  With the virtual machine shut down for the moment I did just that but got an error message (something about "can't read file").  Afterwards, trying to connect to my virtual machine with Hyper-V resulted in the error message "the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".  So how to unlock it?

After scouring the web and trying various procedures I finally found one that worked by using the Powershell.  Here's the short procedure:

1. Search for Powershell and then Run as Administrator.
2. At the command prompt type:  `get-physicaldisk`

In my case the results were:

```
Number FriendlyName           SerialNumber    MediaType   CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage            Size
------ ------------           ------------    ---------   ------- ----------------- ------------ -----            ----
1      SanDisk Ultra II 480GB 16xxxxxxxx96    SSD         False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 447.13 GB
0      WDC WD1001FALS-00E3A0  WD-WCATxxxxxxx9 Unspecified True    OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 931.51 GB
2      Msft Virtual Disk                      SSD         False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select     32 GB
```

As you can see there is an entry called "Msft Virtual Disk" which represents the VM file mounted as a virtual disk.

3. To unmount the virtual disk, from the command prompt type:

```
   Dismount-DiskImage -ImagePath "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual hard disks\Name-Of-Your-Virtual-Machine.vhdx"
```

4. Re-enter the command:  `get-physicaldisk`
   to verify that the virtual disk is unmounted.

After that the virtual disk was unmounted and I was able to successfully connect and load my virtual machine from Hyper-V once again.

I hope this information helps someone!

Comment: Thanks@Rob! THIS saved me!! I had a persistent checkpoint I forced with Merge-VHD and then couldn't boot the VM. No obvious file locks found using ProcExp64 but I did notice the Virtual Disk in Disk Management. This answer confirmed that dismounting was the way to go. All is good now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues a few days ago:

> Microsoft Emulated IDE Controller Error(Instance ID 83F863B-8DCA-9EDA-2CA8B33039B4): Failed to Power on with Error 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process...

I tried to remove the USB Drivers and IDE - CD-ROMs. Re-initiate permissions again, but it didn't solve the issue.

I had to create a new VM and attach the hard disk. It solved the issue.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you will click the virtual drive like computer\user\public\publicdocument\hyper-v\virtual machine\documents and settings the a new drive is opened in My computer. Right click the specified drive and "eject', then go to Hyper-V and start the Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 0):

Very very simple.
 Simply go to vm setting. Then in the left pane just under the IDE controller 1 click DVD Drive and then select none. Job done.

Answer (score 0):

Go the your Hyper-V Manager, locate the failing Machine settings, go to its virtual Hard drive, inspect the drive on the right pane and then reconnect the drive.
Finish the wizard and your machine will start normal.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
Eject new driver than created by click on .vhdx your vm.

1.Open your master/physical FILE MANAGER on windows server than hyper-v installed.

2.Select last driver

3.Right Click on last driver

4.select Eject

5.Now you can start vm in Hyper-v

Comment: "driver" or "drive"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling VM:s with a solution as LabBuilder, you might actually have rebound the parent of a snapshot disk. I.e. using the same disk twice.

That might happen when you try to re-install a Hyper-V lab that has snaphots configured. Then all data disks will be bound twice.

In my case, `Location 1 - 3` has been added once more as `Location 4 - 5`.

[![Hyper-V Settings with the same disks bound twice][1]][1]

To start be able to start the VM, simply remove the additional bound disk images at `Location 3 - 5`.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhdZB.png

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for Powershell and then Run as Administrator.
2. At the command prompt type: get-physicaldisk
3. unmount the virtual disk (Name = "Msft Virtual Disk"), using the command prompt
   Dismount-DiskImage -ImagePath ""
4. Now the file/Virtual disc would be unmouted, go and delete the vhd file .

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the culprit that was using the VHDX file was my backup software Backblaze (bztransmit64.exe), and this persisted even after a reboot (presumably it continued the backup from where it left off post reboot)

Oddly, Process Explorer did not return any hits when searching for the filename of the VHDX file, but I was able to identify the culprit by trying to rename the VHDX in Windows Explorer, nor did it return a handle for bztransmit64 itself

bztransmit64 doesn't show up as running at all in Process Explorer, but shows up normally in Task Manager - never seen this before, caused me some delay in finding the culprit